# Generate a report using jasperReport contain no available data

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'am using JasperReport and ireport 4.0

I want to generate a report contain the word "no available data for this request" When the request do not return data.

How can I do that?

than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rym, you can set "When No Data" template property to "No Data Section" value (in IReport). And then add Static Text (to this new band) with "no available data for this request" text, for example

Comment: ,thank you for the reply , you have said "And then add Static Text (to this new band)" ,what new band you mean! ,I have added the property "No Data Section" to my report and I don't know where I should add the statis text!

Comment: @rym In "Report Inspector" window you cab see "No Data" band. This band name may be grey - in this case you should add this band (Add Band from context menu). After this operation the new section will appear in your template. You can add Static Text to this band (use drag & drop)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Alex K said, or better check if you have any data to process before generating the report, then you can generate another simple report saying "no available data ...", I guess you can save much on computing resources doing it this way.